# Move mutiple inheritance to something similar to the Adapter pattern (with getting/setting part of the attributes dynamically)

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I have legacy code to which I want to add some features but because of many hardcoded connections I need to use an adapter.

```
class ANew:
 def aget():
  ....
 # few methods


class Dlegacy()
  def d()
  ....
 # other many methods


class Clegacy(Dlegacy)
  def c()
  .... 
  # other many methods


class Blegacy(Clegacy)
 def b()
   .... 
   # other many methods


class SomeAdapter:

    def __init__(self, anew_in, blegacy_in):
        self.anew_in = anew_in
        self.blegacy_in = blegacy_in

    def get(self):
        return self.anew_in.aget()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            super().__getattribute__(attr)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.blegacy_in, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if hasattr(self.blegacy_in, attr):
            setattr(self.blegacy_in, attr, value)
        else:
            setattr(self, attr, value)
```

Because `ANew` has few methods/attributes I can redirect the methods of SomeAdapter to the methods from `ANew`, but for the rest of the methods and attributes I want to dynamically redirect them to `Blegacy`

Overriding just `__geattr__` works, but after I introduced `__setattr__` because it has inside `hasattr(self.blegacy_in, attr)` will enter in a recursion loop calling `__getattr__`.

So, I'm trying to avoid this loop. Off course I can use multiple inheritance and SomeAdapter to inherit from `ANew` and `Blegacy` but composition offers more flexibility.